# In every sequence of positive integers, each $17$-sum is even, and each $18$-sum is odd. How many terms can such a sequence have at most?

Tags: combinatorics

In every sequence of positive integers, each $17$-sum is even, and each $18$-sum is odd. How many terms can such a sequence have at most? $\\$
I have been able to figure out that in this sequence of positive integers there are more than $16$ odd integers at least. This is because: $\\$
Let's take {$a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{17}$} to be a sequence of $17$ integers, we know that their sum is even, now if we add another integer let's say $a_{18}$ to this sequence then the new sum should be odd and hence the so-added integer must be odd. $\\$
Hence for every grouping of $17$ integers there should be another odd integer. Now suppose there are less than $16$ odd integers i.e $15$ odd integers. Then if we select a pair in which the $15$ odd and $2$ even
are appearing and then add any other integer i.e even the $18$-sum will come out to be odd which is contradictory !$\\$
Now if there are $16$ odd integers then we can take a $17$-set in which there are $15$ odd and $2$ even, and then to form the $18$-set we can add the $16^\text{th}$ odd number thereby fulfilling the condition. $\\$

Hence the number of odd integers is $\ge16$ . $\\$
Now I am stuck on how to proceed, any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!$\\$
Source : Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel

Comment: What is a $17$-sum?

Comment: sum of 17 integers

Comment: You mean you take an infinite sequence of positive integers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ under the condition that any subsets $\{a_{j_k}, k =1,...,17\}$ and $\{a_{i_k}, k =1,...,18\}$ sum up like $\sum_{k=1}^{17} a_{j_k}$ is odd and $\sum_{k=1}^{18} a_{i_k}$ is even?

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive?

Comment: we have to find the maximum number of integers needed to form such a sequence @Jfischer

Comment: not necessary @ParclyTaxel

Comment: But your question says _maximum_ number of possible integers. The sequence has to be finite somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Since any terms may be chosen, consider $18$ terms. By arbitrarily choosing an element to exclude from the $17$-sum, we show that all the $18$ terms are odd. But this means that all the $17$-sums are *odd*, which is a contradiction.

Hence the sequence may have at most $17$ elements, and having them all even fulfills the conditions.

(If the sums are all consecutive, a similar argument shows that there may be at most $33$ terms.)